# manipulating file using functions

Tags: c++, function

Hi I am trying to write program that a program that allows the user to transfer an amount from an account (the account being text file "shop" which simply contains the value 100).

I want to have it so that the user can make as many transfers as they want, without overdrawing the account. The file also needs to be updated after each transaction. Can anyone help me with where I'm going wrong?

```
int read_balance(void);
void write_balance(int balance);

#include <limits>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{

    std::cout << "You have choosen to transfer an amount" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "How much do you wish to transfer from the shop account?" << std::endl;

    int amount = 0;

    if (std::cin >> amount)
    {
        std::cout << "DEBUG: amount:" << amount << "\n";
        int balance = read_balance();

        if (amount <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Amount must be positive\n";
        }
        else if (balance < amount)
        {
            std::cout << "Insufficient funds\n";
        }
        else
        {
            int new_balance = balance - amount;

            write_balance(new_balance);
            std::cout << "New account balance: " << new_balance << std::endl;
        }

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int read_balance(void)
{
    std::ifstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    f.open("shop.txt");
    int balance;

    f >> balance;
    f.close();
    return balance;
}

void write_balance(int balance)
{
    std::ofstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    f.open("shop.txt");
    f << balance;
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: What's going wrong, exactly? Is there an error message, or is the output not what you expect?

Comment: When I use visual studio and there's a problem with my code it just compiles the most recent code that was working so no error message.

Comment: You mean it *runs* the most recent successful build? You can tell it to build (or rebuild) without running, and that should let you see any errors which occur.

Comment: yea runs sorry, new to this. Here's the errors;

Comment: 1> Build started: Project: delete2, Configuration: Debug Win32--
1>Build started 17/01/2014 16:11:23.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\delete2.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  delete2.cpp
1>c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(7): warning C4627: '#include <limits>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>     Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(22): error C3861: 'read_balance': identifier not found
1>c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(36): error C3861: 'write_balance': identifier not found

Comment: 1>c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(47): error C2601: 'read_balance' : local function definitions are illegal
1>          c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(15): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched
1>c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(58): error C2601: 'write_balance' : local function definitions are illegal
1>          c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(15): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched
1>c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(65): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\delete2\delete2\delete2.cpp(15)' was matched
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: so my code is okay it's MSVC that's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler warns you when using precompiled headers for stdafx.h the `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the first line of code. So it's better to start with

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int read_balance(void);
void write_balance(int balance);
```